# What does jquery .ajaxsubmit pass?

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I am trying to use jquery's form plugin from http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxSubmit and .ajaxsubmit to submit my data in a form however I am not really sure what .ajaxsubmit is passing and how I can read this in my php file.

I have a validate function

```
function validate(formData, jqForm, options) { 
    alert('About to submit: \n\n' + queryString); 
    return true; 
}
```

that shows queryString which is

```
first=testfirstname&last=testlastname&age=90
```

when I use .ajaxsubmit, nothing happens as listed in my script below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {          
    var options = { 
        target:        '#output1', 
        beforeSubmit:  validate,
        success:       showResponse
    };

    //submission 
    $('#myForm').submit(function() { 
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);      
        return false; 
    });
});
```

My form is

```
<form action="comment.php" method="post" id="myForm">
```

I was wondering what format is the data being sent, would I do something with

```
$_REQUEST['first'];
```

and also how would I also pass in an addition value from the `$_SESSION`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the jQuery plugin actually sends the plugin data as `POST`-data to PHP (similar to setting `method="post"` on your `<form>` tag). You can access it like this:

```
$_POST['name_of_field_in_form'];
```

The `name_of_field_in_form` is just the name of a field, for example if you have this code `<input name="email" type="text" />`, you could access it via `$_POST['email'];`.

About your second query, not sure what you mean, but you can use `session_start();` to create a session and after that `$_SESSION` acts like a 'normal' array.